# How to Minify CSS with Webpack when using Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, obfuscation, tailwind-css

When using ReactJS, [Tailwind suggests using CRACO](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) (Create React App Configuration Override). My best attempt based on this [blog post on minifying css names](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda) and the [CRACO docs](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration) has led me to trying the craco.config.js file below. But it still doesn't work with Tailwind.css. Tried it in both the commented locations independently.

Has anyone been able to minify/obfuscate css classnames when using TailwindCSS either via webpack or an external package? Please detail your config file or some step by step instruction if so, as I've been spending months trying to figure this out...

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
            // loaderOptions: {
            //     modules: {
            //         localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]'
            //     },
            //     importLoaders: 1
            // },
        },
        // css: {
        //     loaderOptions: {
        //         modules: {
        //             localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]'
        //         },
        //         importLoaders: 1
        //     },
        // }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minify your CSS by adding [cssnano](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano) as a PostCSS plugin as follows:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            // add cssnano as a plugin here
            plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer'), require('cssnano')],
            // loaderOptions: {
            //     modules: {
            //         localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]'
            //     },
            //     importLoaders: 1
            // },
        },
        // css: {
        //     loaderOptions: {
        //         modules: {
        //             localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]'
        //         },
        //         importLoaders: 1
        //     },
        // }
    },
};
```

Make sure to also install `cssnano` with `npm` or `yarn`.

Obfuscating Tailwind CSS is significantly harder than just minifying it, and in my opinion it's probably not worth the effort. However, there have been [discussions](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/456) on obfuscation before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Definitely appreciate it. I tried installing and adding as you mentioned but the classnames don't change. I also tried `require('cssnano')({ preset: 'default' })` to no avail. Have you made it work using what you mentioned by any chance?

Comment: `cssnano` minifies CSS, but it does not obfuscate it. In my opinion, obfuscation is not worth the effort, since it does not save that much bandwidth after factoring in gzip compression to be worth the trouble. I would recommend just minifying without obfuscating (not many sites obfuscate CSS class names intentionally...)

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'm okay with just minifying that's no problem. It's just simply that adding the code in the craco.config.js file as described doesn't minify it. I assume minifying classNames would still change it from `px-20` to `a74` or something random